# How to save data in a file without overwriting the old data in that file?

Tags: java, android

My code is creating a file to save data into, but it's also overwriting the previous data that was saved previously under that same file name. How do I modify my code in order to save the new data without affecting the old one? I want my data to be saved with a line that separates the old one. Here is my code part of saving:

```
public void buttonSave(View view) {
    File file = new File(path + "/Data.txt");
    String[] saveText = String.valueOf(editText.getText()).split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    editText.setText("");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Save(file, saveText);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i meant programming an android app using android studio

Comment: Show your Save method

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the data from your file into a String and then add new text to the string. After that save the file with the newly added info and you're done. Here's a sample on how to read the file:

```
BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```